# HtmlUnit: disable exception for error 401?

Tags: htmlunit

I'm using HtmlUnit to connect to website X,
inside it's code site X calls site Y,
site Y cannor be accessed because of the firewall, returning a 401 Unauthorized error,
=> the whole call to `WebClient.getPage()` fails with a `FailingHttpStatusCodeException`.

Is there a way to ignore 401 errors and load page X even without stuff from Y?
I already have `webClient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);` in my code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it turned out website Y was called by javascript, as I didn't need js on that page doing `webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);` fixed the problem.

However I still feel like HtmlUnit error reporting should be a bit more smart then: throw exception vs do nothing.